# .NET WPF always get an error

Tags: .net, wpf

Hello I'm learning WPF but I always seem to get an error when I try this:

```
<Window x:Class="Projectosaurus.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Projectosaurus"> //// this is where I mapped my namespace
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse Fill="DarkGreen" Width="100" Height="75" local:Rotation.Angle="60"/>
```

//and when I try to get it here I always get an error that the name (in this case)
"Rotation" does not exist in the namespace (in this case) Projectosaurus, yet it does
I've created a class "Rotation" inside of this project and its Namespace is Projectosaurus,
what am I doing wrong? (I get this every time in every project)

```
namespace Projectosaurus
{
class Rotation : DependencyObject
{


    public static double GetAngle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(AngleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAngle(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(Rotation), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAngleChanged));

    private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
            element.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(
            (double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

**FIXED IT! First time I had this problem yesterday, my immediate thought was to make the
class "public" but it did not work, but that was because I did not rebuild it! Thanks everyone.

Comment: You need to also show us the Projectosaurus class if you want any help.

Comment: Is `Rotation` in the same assembly as your `MainWindow`?  Also, do you get this error *when compiling*, or does it just show up in the "Errors" pane while you are editing?  If the latter, try recompiling the project.

Comment: I get an immediate error when I try to write "local:Rotation..." inside Ellipse Tags.

Comment: Any time you “get an error” remember to show us the full error message, including stack trace. Do not just pick out a few words from the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `Rotation` class **public**. Also make it static and you don't need to inherit from `DependencyProperty` you are using it as an `AttachProperty`.

I don't see where you initialize `<local:Rotation/>`

```
public static class Rotation 
{


public static double GetAngle(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (double)obj.GetValue(AngleProperty);
}

public static void SetAngle(DependencyObject obj, double value)
{
    obj.SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(Rotation), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAngleChanged));

private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = d as UIElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
        element.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(
        (double)e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that previous time, it didn't work as a matter of fact as soon as I write "local" inside Ellipse tags I get the error

Comment: As soon as you write "local" the reason why you get the error because it hasn't build yet. Try rebuilding and the error should go away. Just try making it public and do a rebuild.

Comment: yeah I realized that was stupid of me to say, I'll try right now

Comment: yup it works! my problem was also, that I've tried yesterday with "public" but it didn't work because I did not rebuild it, so I thought the problem was somewhere else, thanks a lot!